# Multiple constraint on type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I did this multiple constraint

```
public class BaseValidation<S, R> 
        where R : BaseRepository 
        where S : BaseService<R>, new()
    {
        public S service;

        public BaseValidation()
        {
            service = new S();
        }
    }
```

Here's the BaseService class

```
public class BaseService<T> where T : BaseRepository, new(){ }
```

And when I build, an error occurs like this...

> 'R' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type

How to properly done this?
Thank you.

Comment: Does `BaseService` have a parameterless constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `new()` constraint to `R` as well, since `T` has that constraint in the definition of `BaseService<T>`:

```
public class BaseValidation<S, R> 
        where R : BaseRepository, new()
        where S : BaseService<R>, new()
{
    public S service;

    public BaseValidation()
    {
        service = new S();
    }
}
```

If you don't actually need that constraint in `BaseService<T>`, just remove it.